# example proof using predicate calculus with equality

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to understand example 4 of section 21 of *First Order Mathematical Logic* by Angelo Margaris:

1. 0 + 0 = 0 + 0 (=)
2. 0 + y = y + 0
3. y' + 0 = y + 0'
4. y + 0' = (y + 0)'
5. y + 0' = (0 + y)'
6. 0 + y' = (0 + y)'
7. 0 + y' = y' + 0 (=, 6, 5, 3)

The only things introduced so far in this section have been the equality axioms and the following two theorems:

T1. $\forall x \forall y (x = y \to y = x)$

T2. $\forall x \forall y \forall z (x = y \land y = z \to x = z)$

It does not seem to me that steps 2-6 can be arrived at from these alone. Are they all assumptions? If they are all assumptions then why are steps 1, 2 and 4 stated?

What does the prime notation denote? Why is step 7 different from step 2?

Comment: I think ' denotes successor (in the natural numbers), and $y+0 = y$ is part of the definition of $+$ in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margaris is a great book, but does require some patience getting to know his particular nomenclature. In addition, as Example 4 of Section 21 illustrates, he is sometimes not as clear as he could have been.

The purpose of this example is *solely* to show how three of the results introduced in the preceding two pages are used in an exemplary proof. These results are:

- Equality Axiom (E1): $\forall x(x=x)$;
- Theorem 1: $\vdash\forall x\forall y(x=y\rightarrow y=x)$;
- Theorem 2: $\vdash\forall x\forall y\forall z(x=y\wedge y=z\rightarrow x=z)$

(E1) is used in step (1) of the proof.  Theorems 1 and 2 are used in step (7). These applications are properly explained in the paragraph following the example on page 106. Why no reasons are given for steps (2)-(6) is because the results required have yet to be introduced in the book. Indeed, Example 4 is exactly those first 8 (of 17) steps given as the proof for Theorem 4 of Section 24 (pages 129-130). Section 24 defines the first-order theory of natural numbers.

> The set of proper symbols of $N$ is $\{\ =\ ,\ '\ ,\ +\ ,\ \cdot \,\ 0\ \}$, where $'$ is the first 1-place operation symbol, $+$ and $\cdot$ are the first two 2-place operation symbols, and $0$ is the first constant symbol. $r'$ is called the successor of $r$.

When you get to Section 24 and Theorem 4 therein, you will find that the justifications for steps (2)-(6) are based on the specific axioms of the natural numbers, an initial theorem of the number system, as well as some substitution theorems that actually immediately follow Example 4 in the book.

I wish this answer could be more interesting to those who do not have the Margaris text, but unfortunately the answer is a consequence of the book's pedantics and not really of a mathematical nature. But for partial completeness, see below for Theorem 4 and first 8 (of 17) steps of its proof covering the base induction step (from which the example above is taken).

> **Theorem 4** (Section 24/Margaris/First Order Number Theory): $\vdash
> \forall x\forall y(x+y=y+x)$
>
> **Proof**: Induction on $x$. $P(x)$ is $x+y=y+x$. First we prove $0+y=y+0$ by induction on $y$.
>
> > 1. $0+0=0+0\qquad$ Equality Axiom $\forall x(x=x)$
> >
> >    > 2. $0+y=y+0\qquad\quad$ induction hypothesis
> >    > 3. $y'+0=y+0'\qquad\ \ \ $ Number Theorem $\forall x\forall y(x'+y=x+y')$.
> >    > 4. $y+0'=(y+0)'\qquad$ Number Axiom $\forall x\forall y(x+y'=(x+y)')$.
> >    > 5. $y+0'=(0+y)'\qquad$ substitution of (2) and (4).
> >    > 6. $0+y'=(0+y)'\qquad$ Number Axiom $\forall x\forall y(x+y'=(x+y)')$.
> >    > 7. $0+y'=y'+0\qquad\ \ \ $ Theorems 1/2 from above.
> >
> > $8$. $\forall y(0+y=y+0\rightarrow0+y'=y'+0)\qquad$ deduction from (2) to (7) and generalization